# Get base64 encoding when uploading a file

Tags: php

I am trying to get the base64 encoding for a file when uploading in PHP using:

```
$sound = base64_encode( file_get_contents( $_FILES["sound"]["tmp_name"] ) );
```

but it's returning:

> Notice: file_get_contents(): send of 8192 bytes failed with errno=104 Connection reset by peer

Is it possible to do this without saving the file to the server?

Comment: Is `$_FILES["sound"]["tmp_name"]` a URL of some sort?

Comment: im not sure what you mean by that? its PHP code

Comment: Your error message indicates that `file_get_contents` is making a HTTP call, which is unusual for a file upload. Make sure `$_FILES["sound"]["tmp_name"]` contains what you expect (it should typically be something like `/tmp/<random characters>`) but I don't think it is in your case, which is odd.

Comment: ["tmp_name"]=> string(27) "/home/i/t/itl/tmp/phpBgtpve"

Comment: try `var_dump( file_exists($_FILES["sound"]["tmp_name"]));`

Comment: thats returning `bool(true)`

Comment: Its very strange .. Becouse "Connection reset by peer" is a network message ...

Comment: Are you PC has a linux system? or "/home/i/t/itl/tmp/..." is a virtual path on another OS like Windows OR MacOs?

Comment: try `if( FALSE === fopen( $_FILES["sound"]["tmp_name"] )) echo 'its NETWORK'; else echo 'its LOCAL'; `. Also please answer prvious quo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the filename is too long. Please check the length of the string you are passing to file_get_contents:

```
echo strlen($_FILES["sound"]["tmp_name"]));
```

As far as I feel your server might be configured improperly. Maybe you need to check the temp path for file uploads if it's not too long.

Comment: 27 characters is to long? seems rather unlikely.

Comment: He say's: `["tmp_name"]=> string(27) "/home/i/t/itl/tmp/phpBgtpve"`

Comment: Well this number will be different on different servers :) I am wondering about charlie's setup.

Comment: Your suggestion is impossible! becouse most config files has more length of path then 27, and most of deamons dont will be started on that system

Comment: 27 is a path len of the file what wants to be opened, not about min path len

Comment: Hey do you really know the exact situation of charlie?